# Scroll to hide Javascript modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How would I hide the modal as soon as its scrolled down?

```
$('#dialog').onscroll(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});
```

Comment: There is no `onscroll` function in jQuery, and even less a `onsroll`. `scroll` exists tho.

Answer (score 1):

can this meet your need?

```
$('window').onscroll = function () {
    $('.window').hide();
}
```

you need to learn how to bind an event.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you are already using jQuery, try the following:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  $('#dialog').hide();
});
```

You were using the wrong event (`onsroll` instead of `scroll`) on the wrong object (`#dialog` instead of `window`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write something like this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
            $('#dialog').hide();
            $('.window').hide();
        });
```